# IllegalMonitorStateException when using Vaadin Shiro and Hazelcast

Tags: authentication, vaadin, shiro, vaadin7, hazelcast

I am trying to mix two web example applications that use Apache Shiro:

https://github.com/vaadin-kim/shiro-example

https://github.com/stormpath/shiro-hazelcast-web-sample

I forked the shiro-example for vaadin and made my changes under the module shiro-login-outside-vaadin-app:

https://github.com/poseidonjm/shiro-example

```
git clone https://github.com/poseidonjm/shiro-example.git
cd shiro-example
cd shiro-login-outside-vaadin-app
mvn package
```

I deploy the .war file to Apache Tomcat 7 and after login I get the next exception:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:240)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
causa raíz
com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1429)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1383)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
causa raíz
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:155)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1260)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:460)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.unlockSession(VaadinService.java:615)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:633)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:495)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1365)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
```

shiro.ini

```
[main]
# use native session management so we can configure our own session clustering:
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
# we have configured Hazelcast to enforce a TTL for the activeSessions Map.  No need for Shiro to invalidate!
sessionManager.sessionValidationSchedulerEnabled = false
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

# configure Hazelcast as our Shiro CacheManager.  Adding session capacity is as easy as adding hazelcast nodes!
cacheManager = com.stormpath.samples.shiro.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp

[users]
# format: username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
demo = demo

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/logout = logout
/VAADIN/** = authc
/** = authc
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="vaadin-uitest" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>assembly</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Make sure any request you want accessible to Shiro is filtered. /* 
        catches all -->
    <!-- requests. Usually this filter mapping is defined first (before all 
        others) to -->
    <!-- ensure that Shiro works in subsequent filters in the filter chain: -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything Hazelcast specific in the stacktraces.

Comment: Hazelcast is being used as the cache manager of shiro. I wonder if it is a problem of vaadin and shiro native sessions

Comment: vaadin works fine with shiro native sessions e.g. Ehcache as the cache manager https://github.com/poseidonjm/shiro-example/tree/master/shiro-ehcache-outside-vaadin-app

Comment: I experience the same thing, did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: no, unfortunately. Give +1, if you think is a valid question